# How to remove interior stone wall facade

Tags: walls, stone

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to remove the rock wall facade around the fireplace and on the whole wall?

The floor in the room is currently old vinyl that we are going to rip out and replace.

Comment: Currently this question is opinion based which will get flagged and removed. Do you have a more specific question that you can ask?

Comment: if that was my wall, i would paint it white first ... then i would tear it down is i still disliked it ... nothing more than my opinion

Answer (score 3):

I use an air chicle with a wide blade but a hammer and wide chisel will work.
Start at a grout line and hold the chisel at a 45, one or 2 good wacks and you will be to the base lay the chisel as flat as you can maybe 30 degrees for the first one and many times a good sharp wack will pop the stone in some cases it will shatter after a few adjustments of your angle you will start popping larger chunks.
I have a tile chipper on a pole it can be used but is harder on a wall than on a floor.

I find the trick is getting the right angle so 1 wack will take a stone at a time with a 6” or 8” chisel.

On ply wood sometimes can be tough.
When it ends up being Sheetrock after I punch through I tear the entire wall out.
When backer board and thinset it comes off mastic can go either way.

Wear safety glasses or a face shield some pieces do normally shatter.
A dust mask can also be a good idea lots of dust doing this.
I put tarps down or a wheelbarrow in the room and get good at piping right into the wheelbarrow, with the tarp 2 people grab the ends before it gets two heavy and take it to the dumpster.